# Implementing a SPDY Client using Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, spdy

I am trying to use SPDY from Python 2.7. I found the Python-spdylay library as a wrapper around the C implementation. I realize that some parts of the library are Python 3 only.

I would like to reproduce the behaviour of the following example from the Python-spdylay documentation on Python 2.7 (http://spdylay.sourceforge.net/python.html#simple-spdy-client):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# The example SPDY client.  You need Python 3.3 or later because we
# use TLS NPN.
#
# Usage: spdyclient.py URL...
#
import sys
import spdylay

class MyStreamHandler(spdylay.BaseSPDYStreamHandler):
    def on_header(self, nv):
        sys.stdout.write('Stream#{}\n'.format(self.stream_id))
        for k, v in nv:
            sys.stdout.write('{}: {}\n'.format(k, v))

    def on_data(self, data):
        sys.stdout.write('Stream#{}\n'.format(self.stream_id))
        sys.stdout.buffer.write(data)

    def on_close(self, status_code):
        sys.stdout.write('Stream#{} closed\n'.format(self.stream_id))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    uris = sys.argv[1:]
    spdylay.urlfetch(uris, MyStreamHandler)
```

In other words, I just want to fetch a url and provide callbacks, but using SPDY.

PyPi provides this statement

> The core library API works with Python 2 and 3. But ThreadedSPDYServer
>   requires Python 3.3 because it uses TLS NPN extension.

I assume that this means that `spylay.urlfetch` and `spdylay.BaseSPDYStreamHandler` use `ThreadedSPDYServer`, so maybe there is a non-threaded SPDYServer, that I can use?

Comment: Just a quick reminder that SPDY is in the process of being deprecated in favour of HTTP 2.0, at least when taking Google's Chromium as a reference: http://blog.chromium.org/2015/02/hello-http2-goodbye-spdy-http-is_9.html

Comment: Yep, HTTP2 borrows from SPDY.